# Facebook javascript API: get logged in username + image

Tags: javascript, facebook

I would like to know if theres a way to get the username and the profile image from the user that im logged in to on facebook. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
graph.facebook.com/me
graph.facebook.com/me/picture
```

Make sure to authenticate the user in your app.

Comment: {
   "error": {
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "message": "An active access token must be used to query information about the current user."
   }
}

Comment: Which would mean you don't have a current user. You need to authenticate the user in your app.

Comment: But i want to display the picture and name of any user visiting my page. Do i just create an app for that?

Comment: In order to do that, yes - the user would have to authenticate with facebook on your site using facebook connect and authorize you to have access to that information. You can't just access their facebook cookie and account.